# Why does my compiler show a "no suitable constructor found for Window(int,int,String,Game)" error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm learning to build a game with this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws

I've went over the code a few times now and I can't seem to find a discrepancy between my code and the code used in the tutorial. I'm also getting this information in my terminal:

new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Let's Build A Game!", this);
                ^
    constructor Window.Window(GraphicsConfiguration) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

```
constructor Window.Window() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

constructor Window.Window(Frame) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

constructor Window.Window(Window) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

constructor Window.Window(Window,GraphicsConfiguration) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here is my Game.java:

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8073316534757788976L;

        public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH/12*9;

        private Thread thread;
        private boolean running = false;

        public Game(){
                new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Let's Build A Game!", this);
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
                thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();
                running = true;
        }

        public synchronized void stop(){
                try{
                        thread.join();
                        running = false;
                }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void run(){
                long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
                double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
                double ns = 100000000 / amountOfTicks;
                double delta = 0;
                long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int frames = 0;
                while(running){
                        long now = System.nanoTime();
                        delta += (now - lastTime) /ns;
                        lastTime = now;
                        while(delta >= 1){
                                tick();
                                delta--;
                        }
                        if(running){
                                render();
                        }
                        frames++;

                        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                                timer+=1000;
                                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                                frames = 0;
                        }
                }
                stop();
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
                new Game();
        }

        private void tick(){

        }
        private void render(){
                BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
                if(bs==null){
                        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
                        return;
                }

                Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

                g.dispose();
                bs.show();

        }
}
```

And here is my Window.java:

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Window extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3359827712233484029L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();


    }
}
```

Anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Class `Game` in the presented code `import java.awt.*`. There is a class [`Window`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/13/latestSpec/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html) in `java.awt`. This class does not have a constructor with argument list `int, int, String, Game` and "shadows" the `Window` class in package `com.tutorial.main` for `Game`. Thus the compile error.

One should not use the asterisk (`*`) for importing, but use specific imports instead. If specific imports are used (as shown in the tutorial provided), the error will not occur.

Comment: Thank you! Now when I run it the class Window is recognized and the Game class isn't recognized within Window despite them being located in the same folder. Do I need to call each class within each other in some other way then I have above?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)